# How to create phone auth credential like Uber?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, firebase-authentication

I want to create Phone Auth Credential like Uber, I mean when user use the app for the first time he has to complete his registration information after phone authentication then he will be able to move to DriverHome Activity, but next time he uses the authentication he will redirect to the DriverHome Activity automatically.

I've used Phone Auth Credential code and it works fine but I need to add the part is responsible for checking if the user registered before or not.

public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String verificationId;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

DatabaseReference users;


ProgressBar progressBar;
TextInputEditText editText;
AppCompatButton buttonSignIn;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification_code);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);
    buttonSignIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

    String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
    sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);

    // save phone number
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREF",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    editor.apply();

    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                editText.setError("Enter code...");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    });

}

private void verifyCode(String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
}

private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, DriverHomeActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);


                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            number,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallBack
    );

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        verificationId = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            editText.setText(code);
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before onCreateView
check if sharepreference has phone number  if it has then using startActivity(new Intent(this, DriverHomeActivity.class); to go directly to driverhome activity

if sharepreference has no phone number then 
Save phone number in sharepreference if onComplete function of  signInWithCredential return successful using isSucessful

```
public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String verificationId;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
DatabaseReference users;
ProgressBar progressBar;
TextInputEditText editText;
AppCompatButton buttonSignIn;
SharedPreferences prefs ;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREF",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    //add this line
    if(prefs.getString("phoneNumber", null) != null)
      startActivity(new Intent(this, DriverHomeActivity.class));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification_code);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);
    buttonSignIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

    String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
    sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);

    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                editText.setError("Enter code...");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    });

}

private void verifyCode(String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
}

private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

      //insert data if task is successful
                       editor.putString("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                       editor.apply();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, DriverHomeActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);


                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            number,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallBack
    );

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        verificationId = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            editText.setText(code);
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```